# Does SharePoint 2003 has Workflow?

Tags: workflow, 2003

I have one simple question, Does SharePoint 2003 has Workflow? because I'm working with client who has SharePoint 2003 and I'm not sure if it has workflow or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Yes it does, the following link is an introduction:</strike>

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010164124.aspx

**EDIT:**
Sorry about that, 2003 does not support Workflows out of the box. There are thoug various third-party tools that let's you work with Workflows also in 2003, (2.0). Here is a blog post to get you started: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ssahmed/spsworkflow09112006025618AM/spsworkflow.aspx

Comment: But in right side you'll find Applies to:
SharePoint Server 2007, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, I'm using SharePoint Server 2003 and Windows SharePoint 2.0.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that! I read WSS 3.0 in your question somehow. Unfortunately the answer is another for WSS 2.0